# Password-protected pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, adobe

I got this error while testing my code.

System.ArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password

I got the original password of the pdf file , but I do not know how to apply it in aspx.cs page. I saw some answers here like the PdfReader.unethicalreading = true; but I dont want to use it since I got the password for the pdf. For example the password of the pdf is "1234". Please help , this is my first time using Itextsharp and Adobe LiveCycle Designer. I dont want to use thirdparty software , I just want to use the password "1234" as an argument at the backend to access the pdf file.

Comment: Could you add some code to demonstrate what you are doing?

Comment: Check out the docu? http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-decrypt-pdf-document-owner-password

Comment: @Florian thanks , will read this and try to use this code as a reference to see if this can fix my problem.